# Is there an official blueprint of Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

I would love to make Hogwarts in Minecraft, but I have no idea what the whole castle looks like, or where specific rooms are inside. I have seen plenty of angles of it, but what I would like is some sort of official layout or blueprint of the whole shebang. Does such a resource exist?

Comment: The interior would be hard to do, because it can rearrange itself, and there are rooms which don't comply to the rules of Euclidian space.

Comment: If you do, please post a link here!

Comment: I myself have built Hogwarts in Minecraft and you can check out my images if it will help you out! http://www.facebook.com/StaplersHogwarts

Comment: @vsz - Pistons and redstone can make rearranging rooms (though not often compactly), and Nether portals can defy Euclidian space.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

J.K. Rowling drew a basic layout of Hogwarts and its surrounding grounds:

[image: http://www.flickr.com/photos/slytherincess/6883262666/]

I will see if I can find any other drawings having to do with Hogwarts specifically. I think the movies are really wonderful, and they have J.K. Rowling's input and approval, so using ideas from the movies should be within the spirit of canon, if not perfectly, technically canon. **Sachin Shekhar** has already mentioned the *Order of the Phoenix* video game; make sure you get another source or two verifying the game is based on official movie blueprints, as most movies have only partial sets and a lot of the *Harry Potter* movies are filmed in front of the green screen. Enjoy building Hogwarts!

Comment: +1 for the grounds map. Would you happen to know a rough scale of that map?

Comment: @GabeWillard -- I'm terrible at math so I wouldn't begin to muster a guess, and I don't know the scale from canon or J.K. Rowling. However -- and this would be time-consuming -- if you were to re-read the books, there are hints here and there as to the size of different aspects of Potterverse. I believe Hogwarts has 7 levels (as opposed to the, what, twenty-five we see in the movie when looking up at the changing staircases). The movie *OotP* shows the scale of Azkaban (it's *huge*). Thank you for the +1 :)

Comment: Hmm. In *Quidditch Through the Ages*, it says that a regulation Quidditch pitch is 500 feet long and 180 feet wide at the center. That would make the scale somewhere roughly around 1":250'. So now you know. :D Connecting all the pieces of where rooms are located within the castle is the hard part, now. :P

Comment: @GabeWillard - You could take screenshots of the Marauder's Map to help place the different rooms. :)

Comment: I found this quote and thought of this question. **Joshua from Navigation Primary School:** How were you involved in making the Harry Potter films and did Hogwarts look like you had imagined it? **JKR:** *Hogwarts looked just as I imagined it. It was the most bizarre experience when I walked onto the set of the Great Hall; it really was like walking into my own brain*. So I think you could use the movie sets in your quest to design Hogwarts.

Answer (score 11):

Use [official video game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Potter_and_the_Order_of_the_Phoenix_%28video_game%29) of *Harry Potter & the Order of the Phoenix*. It uses **official movie blueprints**, J.K. Rowling's drawings and books' descriptions to recreate known places of Hogwarts. Its not an action game. The main objective of game is **to explore Hogwarts** & follow story of movie/book. You can visit almost all parts of Hogwarts & **stop to look around**. You can use it to create Hogwarts in Minecraft.

Comment: Sounds like quite an undertaking!

Answer (score 3):

You can actually [buy a replica of the Marauder's Map](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0026PW67W).

This (in theory) provides a blueprint of Hogwarts. However according to the customer reviews, it does not provide a proper map, since major locations are missing.

Answer (score 1):

### Lego recently released a [beautiful Hogwarts castle](https://shop.lego.com/en-US/product/Hogwarts-Castle-71043).

Buy it, read the instruction booklet, and follow the exact steps in Minecraft.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Lego is "licenced" rather than "official". It's rarely (if ever) to scale and large sections of the castle (as described in either the film or the books) will be missing.

Comment: @Valorum For Minecraft, it's the best you'll get.

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent map that can be found at http://www.oddment-tweak.com/, that is very helpful in getting an idea as to how Hogwarts is laid out.

Comment: @ Niall: In this case "including the essential part" should be copy here all maps from the remote site: I do not think this is acceptable. There is the Wayback Machine for old invalid liks. This answer is good as any other.

Comment: The Harper Robertson map isn't canon. It's fan-made; http://readingharry.com/news/harper-robertson-vision-of-hogwarts/